# the verb "have" in present perfect: How can I express repetition of having?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

I learned that you "have" not momentary, so you can say "I have had my dog for five years" or etc. using "had" in a meaning of continuation.

But I think in this case the action of having problem is a moment as they does have during a long time:

> These cherry trees live more than a thousand year. They experienced problems many times in their life till now. People have taken care of the trees, and the trees still have blossoms in every spring.

Can I say like this in a meaning of repeated experiences?

> These trees live for many years and have had problems during those years.

or should I say like this?

> These trees live for many years and have problems during those years.

I don't know how to express it. The trees are still living.

Comment: Unfortunately, your sentences are not great English, and the concept of trees "having problems" is such a strange one that it's difficult for me to understand how to answer your question well. Are the trees dead or not? Does the question work just as well with people living 80 years? It's much easier to understand a sentence about people having problems than trees.

Comment: @gotube Thank you so much for the advice! I'll add the details.

Comment: _These trees live for many years_ sounds like a general statement about cherry trees. You could say "These trees (meaning a particular group) are very old, and have had problems during their long life".

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I see!  Thank you so much, thank you for your help..!